# Send auto email on delay for each MySQL entry

Tags: php, mysql

I currently have a MySQL database that sends an auto email each time a new record is entered. I need to also send a reminder email to the email address in each row 5 days after it is inserted. What is the best way to do this? Can I use a MySQL trigger or a cron job? I will likely need step by step instructions, if it isn't through PHP. I've done quite a bit of searching but can't find exactly what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 1):

A cron job is what you need. The php file doing the cron needs to query the table for rows where the entry date is equal to 5 days ago. The mysql query is:

```
SELECT `email` FROM `entries` WHERE date(`entrytimestamp`) = date_sub(curdate(), INVERVAL 5 DAY);
```

Hopefully this gets you started in the right direction. You'll need to make sure that the php file cannot be called outside of cron, that cron only happens once a day, or maybe keep a separate table logging the emails where you would add a "NOT IN `email_log`" condition to make sure that you don't double up on emails to someone.